# Loading the datas from the Web service

Tags: c#

HI

I wanted to load the datas from the master tables for example Prefix,Suffix etc all are in DB tables . I wanted to fetch the all the details within the single request . I want any generic idea for above  using the dictionary like that in C#

Thanks In Advance
Sekar

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general making it difficult to answer with sufficient detail.

Why not try some of the Web Service tutorials on line, and come back to Stack Overflow if you have trouble with anything from the tutorials.

This [Tutorial](http://www.deitel.com/articles/csharp_tutorials/20051126/csharpWebServices_Part1.html) looks quite good

Hope this helps,